# WooCommerce Webhooks - Overwrite Webhook build process bug

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I have the following code for overriding the webhook build process and add the variation objects if the product is variable:

```
// Hook to the webhook build process and add your variations objects.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_webhook_payload', 'dolly_woocommerce_webhook_payload', 10, 4 );
function dolly_woocommerce_webhook_payload( $payload, $resource, $resource_id, $id ) {
    // Remove the filter to eliminate the recursion calls.
    remove_filter( 'woocommerce_webhook_payload', 'dolly_woocommerce_webhook_payload', 10 );

    // Create a WC_Webhook class with the webhook id.
    $wc_webhook = new WC_Webhook( $id );

    // Bail early if the resource is not product.
    if ( 'product' !== $resource ) {
        return $payload;
    }

    // Bail early if the product type is not variable.
    $product = new WC_Product( $resource_id );
    if ( 'variable' === $product->get_type() ) {
        return $payload;
    }   

    // Build the payload of each product variation.
    $variations = $payload['variations'];
    foreach( $variations as $variation ) {
        $variations_objs[] = $wc_webhook->build_payload( $variation );
    }

    // Add the varitions to the payload.
    $payload['variations_objs'] = $variations_objs;

    // Add the filter again and return the payload.
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_webhook_payload', 'dolly_woocommerce_webhook_payload', 10, 4 );
    return $payload;
}
```

Unfortunately, when hitting "Save changes" on a variation while this is active, the variation doesn't stop saving.

The payload I receive to my endpoint seems to be the one before the save process has finished, not afterwards. So, basically the value that's been entered in beforehand, as if the saving didn't happen, yet.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the `===` as in `if ( 'variable' === $product->get_type() )` just a typo in the question? Because I believe it should be `!==` ..?

Comment: The code comes from this question I asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57006733/woocommerce-hooks-product-update-deliver-variation-objects-instead-of-ids/. It uses !==, which I was confused about, as === makes more sense, as you said. But using === still doesn't take care of the infinite loading issue, unfortunately. Forgot to mention that, sorry!

Comment: "=== makes more sense, as you said. But using ===" - I think you meant to type "!==", because I asked you to use `!==` and *not* `===` which seems to be a typo in the original code. But are you certain that using `!==` doesn't help?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant to say, sorry. Using !== gives me another error that variations_objs could not be found. Although I would have expected that error with ===, as the code would bail early if the product is not variable. So, there still seems to be a bug in the code, despite using !==. However, the infinite loading was caused because I set async delivery to false using the woocommerce_webhook_deliver_async filter. Still, I would want the payload to be delivered immediately, so it's unfortunate...

Comment: I'm just wondering how did you solve the issue? :)

Comment: It seems as if woocommerce fires the product save event before the variations are saved. Therefore, it gives me the variations with the field values before saving. So instead I hooked the product save and variation save directly.

Comment: I see. And hopefully that helps someone else. =)